# Why is my twitter widget does not work properly and does not display content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, joomla

I have one page where is twitter widget which just show blank grey content with just twitter logo, so there should be show twitter post.

Here is the part of this code where is this twitter widget :

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <p><a><img class="img-circle img-responsive" data-src="holder.js/30x30"   alt="Twitter placeholder image"></a><a><img class="img-circle img-responsive"   data-src="holder.js/30x30" alt="Twitter placeholder image"></a><a>
  <img class="img-circle img-responsive" data-src="holder.js/30x30" alt="Twitter  placeholder image"></a></p>
</div>
```

And please help why this widget is doesn't display and what I should do than this widget will be working.

This page is on Joomla 1.5 and I know I have the page on old Joomla and I can't do nothing with this.

Answer (score 0):

At first You should update Your Joomla to new version.
It is not safe to use old 1.5

If You want some help with that please contact me :)

Comment: I can't update my page to new joomla because then my page will be mixed and doesn't work

Comment: What do You mean "be mixed"? Also give us link to Your page.